# Backward compatibility of Include keyword in Indexes for SQL Server 2000

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, t-sql, sql-server-2000

I am running a DEV database on SQL Server 2008 and the production is on SQL Server 2000. I was being asked to work on a stored procedure timeout issue which was running on prod database. So, I was a given a dump of the SQL Server 2000 database on my DEV server (2008)

I tried few options and found that adding few indexes (with `INCLUDE` keyword) helped a lot. Now SQL Server 2000 does not support the `Include` keyword. What could be the possible index script for SQL Server 2000?

My script looks something like this:

```
CREATE INDEX _dta_ABC ON dbo.tbl
(
  COL_A ASC,
  COL_B ASC
) INCLUDE (COL_D,COL_E)
GO.
```

Comment: Ideally you will want to run a development environment that has the same platform as your production environment (ie SQL 2000). Can't think of much worse than solving a problem only to find that it can't run on your production system.

Comment: There just simply is **no equivalent** for `INCLUDE` in SQL Server 2000. Period. Time to upgrade! The only thing you could do is put these two extra columns into the index itself - adds overhead and makes the index bigger and less efficient - but that's all you can do on a 13-year old SQL Server **2000** database system.....